# Unresolved import `calamine`

Tags: rust

I want to chain up my excel database with Rust.
I wrote the following code, but some error occurred.

```rust
use calamine::{open_workbook,Render,xlsx};// 

fn main(){
    let xl_book_path="Your Excle Book Path.xlsx";
    let met wb: Xlsx<_> = opne_workbook(Xl_book_path).expect("cannot open xl book");
}
```

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `calamine`
  --> Aut.rs:1:5
   | 1 | use calamine::{open_workbook,Render,xlsx};
       |     ^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `calamine`?
   |   = help: consider adding `extern crate calamine` to use the `calamine` crate

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
```

I thought the cause was missing `calamine` in Cargo.toml,
so I added calamine to Cargo.toml.

```ini
[dependencies] calamine = "0.18.0"
```

But the error still appears.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you not add `extern crate calamine` to your code intentionally?

Comment: Thank you reply.I don't know "extern crate calamine" ,
So I added calamine code with Cargo.toml (line 8,9).
Did you mean need to add code?

Comment: That depends on the Rust edition you've set in your cargo.toml. Do you have any "edition = ..." line in there?

Comment: You should post your cargo.toml, significant parts of main.rs as they are (not re-written by hand - note that you have a typo in "opne_workbook" above), and the commands you use to try to build/run the program. That would help understanding the problem.

Comment: version = "0.1.0" edition = "2021"

Comment: Are you using Cargo for building, or calling `rustc` directly?

Comment: Using Cargo for bulding.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the answer from [cafce25](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442760/cafce25), the right dependency since october 2022 is `calamine = "0.19.1"`.
There are some typo and cases mistakes in the original code, so here is the corrected code :

```
use calamine::{open_workbook,Reader,Xlsx};

fn main(){
    let xl_book_path="Your Excle Book Path.xlsx";
    #[allow(unused_mut)]
    #[allow(unused_variables)]
    let mut wb: Xlsx<_> = open_workbook(xl_book_path).expect("cannot open xl book");
}
```

While writing rust code, you should care on names because the langage is case sensitive :

1. line 1 : changed Re**n**der to `Reader`
2. line 1 : changed **x**lsx to `Xlsx`
3. line 7 : changed m**e**t to `mut`
4. line 7 : changed op**ne**_workbook to `open_workbook`
5. line 7 : changed **X**l_book_path to `xl_book_path`

Additional resources :

- [Dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/dependencies.html) are well explained in the cargo guide
- You can use the [cargo add command](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-add.html) to manage dependencies
- Some examples about calamine usage on [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/calamine/0.19.1), on [doc.rs](https://docs.rs/calamine/latest/calamine/) and on [github.com](https://github.com/tafia/calamine/tree/master/examples)
- And more informations about [naming conventions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/style/naming/README.html)

Hope it will be fine to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To add a dependency the `[dependencies]` section should look like this:

```ini
[dependencies]
calamine = "0.19.1"
```

you can't put them in the same line.

you can then run the project with `cargo run` from within the project directory (where the `Cargo.toml` is) and it should find `calamine`